# Why is the +initialize method of Core Data managed objects being called twice?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a managed core data object with a `+initialize` method. (If it matters, I am looking to use that method to initialize a static variable that is expensive to to set up.) While testing that initialization code I was surprised to discover that the `+initialize` method is getting called twice.

The first time `initialize` is being called `self` is defined as `(Class) MyClass`, as I would expect.

The second time `initialize` is being called `self` is defined as `(Class) MyClass_MyClass_`, which leads me to suspect some sort of unusual initialization for Core Data managed objects.

While this doesn't pose a problem for me (I can just test to see if the static variable has already been initialized, which I would do anyway, to handle ubclassing), it makes me suspect that Core Data is doing something in the object or class lifecycle that I don't understand. Can someone explain to me what is going on in this `MyClass_MyClass_` `+initialize` method invocation?

Comment: To clarify, I understand +initialize, it just seems that the implementation of Core Data is creating a subclass of the object behind the scenes. I wondered what that subclass is doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accessor methods for Core Data properties are dynamically created at runtime.
This works by creating a subclass `MyClass_MyClass_` (of `MyClass`) and adding the
necessary methods to the subclass.

Core Data also does some tricks to hide the fact
that that the objects of your entity are actually instances of the subclass:

```
e = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyClass" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSLog(@"%@", [e class]);               // --> MyClass
NSLog(@"%s", object_getClassName(e));  // --> MyClass_MyClass_
```

Perhaps it becomes even more obvious if you don't set a custom class for your entity.
In that case the output is

```
NSLog(@"%@", [e class]);               // --> NSManagedObject
NSLog(@"%s", object_getClassName(e));  // --> NSManagedObject_MyClass_
```

So `e` "looks like" an instance of `NSManagedObject`, but is indeed an instance
of a dynamically created subclass `NSManagedObject_<EntityName>_`. This subclass
implements all the accessor methods (which are unique to this entity).

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly my suspicion, but found it odd that I couldn't find reference anywhere to Core Data implementing its dynamic accessors via dynamically created subclasses. I had originally assumed that the dynamic methods were swizzled directly into the `MyClass` class until I started investigating this.

Comment: @DavidOgren: Method swizzling works only per class, not per instance. If you have two different entities and don't assign a custom class, then implementing the accessory via swizzling would be difficult, as all object are instances of NSManagedObject. - Unfortunately, I do not have a definite reference that it works like this. I might have read something about it but I cannot remember where. - Another indicator might be that when the subclass is initialized, you'll find something like `[NSManagedObject(_PFDynamicAccessorsAndPropertySupport) classForEntity:]` in the stack backtrace.

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense to me now. Thanks again. When pondering this at first, I had forgotten the case where there was no custom class to swizzle.

Answer (score 0):

From [Apples documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/initialize) on `NSObject` I gather it is normal behaviour: The runtime sends initialize to each class in a program just before the class, or any class that inherits from it, is sent its first message from within the program. The runtime sends the initialize message to classes in a thread-safe manner. Superclasses receive this message before their subclasses. The superclass implementation may be called multiple times if subclasses do not implement initialize—the runtime will call the inherited implementation—or if subclasses explicitly call [super initialize]. If you want to protect yourself from being run multiple times, you can structure your implementation along these lines...

```
+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [ClassName class]) {
    // ... do the initialization ...
   }
}
```

Why you don't use the awakeFrom... methods `NSManagedObject` offers?

Comment: You may want to consider using `+load`, which won't get repeated calls.

Comment: @Volker, I'm not really sure how awakeFrom... methods would help me. Am I missing something? (Also, I can easily make this work with +initialize, it just surprised me and I didn't like not understanding what was going behind the scenes with the extra subclass.)

Comment: @TomHarrington, thanks for the idea. Interesting thought. I think that I'll stick with initialize though, as it's easy to ensure once only initialization. And +load would push up the initialization to very, very early in the lifecycle.

Comment: @DavidOgren i thought more in the line of some kind of transient data  that needs to be calculated and thus thought about methods like `awakeFromInsert:` or `awakeFromFetch: for example. But I now with some more thinking about it see why that wouldn't work.