# What does the type class_class_* mean in xcode debugger?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, magicalrecord, mogenerator

I was testing if an object belonged to a certain class with kiwi, and while debugging, i found that the object was of a weird kind of class:

[image: http://imageshack.com/a/img834/7918/wi8v.png]

Does anyone know what that means?

I'm using magical record to create a core data instance of the object and mogenerator to create the managed object subclass.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21683502/1187415. The question is slightly different but I think the same answer applies here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do i test the kind of class with kiwi?
    [[expectFutureValue(service) shouldEventually] beKindOfClass:[Service class]];

I'm using this to test the class and it doesn't work

Comment: `[service isKindOfClass:[Service class]]` should return YES. But I have no experience with Kiwi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the answer to [Why is the +initialize method of Core Data managed objects being called twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682251/why-is-the-initialize-method-of-core-data-managed-objects-being-called-twice), the Core Data framework
automatically creates subclasses of your `NSManagedObject` subclass to implement the
accessor methods at runtime. In your case, `Service_Service_` is a subclass of `Service`,
created at runtime.

To check if an object is of a certain class, use `isKindOfClass`:

```
[service isKindOfClass:[Service class]]
```

which returns `YES` also for instances of subclasses.